# Apache Beam KafkaIO - Write to Multiple Topics

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-beam, apache-beam-kafkaio

Currently, I'm working on Apache Beam Pipeline implementation which consumes data from three different Kafka topics, and after some processing, I create three types of objects adding those data taken from the above-mentioned Kafka topics. Finally, it is required to publish those three objects into three different Kafka topics.
It is possible to read from multiple topics using `withTopics` method in `KafkaIO.read` but I did not find a KafkaIO feature to write to multiple topics.

I would like to get some advice on how to do this in the most ideal way, appreciate it if anyone can provide some code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with 3 different sinks on a `PCollection`, example :

```java
    private transient TestPipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create();

    @Test
    public void kafkaIOSinksTest(){
        PCollection<String> inputCollection = pipeline.apply(Create.of(Arrays.asList("Object 1", "Object 2")));
        
        inputCollection.apply(KafkaIO.<Void, String>write()
                .withBootstrapServers("broker_1:9092,broker_2:9092")
                .withTopic("topic1")
                .withValueSerializer(new StringSerializer())
                .values());

        inputCollection.apply(KafkaIO.<Void, String>write()
                .withBootstrapServers("broker_1:9092,broker_2:9092")
                .withTopic("topic2")
                .withValueSerializer(new StringSerializer())
                .values());

        inputCollection.apply(KafkaIO.<Void, String>write()
                .withBootstrapServers("broker_1:9092,broker_2:9092")
                .withTopic("topic3")
                .withValueSerializer(new StringSerializer())
                .values());
    }
```

In this example, the same `PCollection` is sinked in 3 different topics, via multi sinks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `KafkaIO.<K, V>writeRecords()` for that. It takes a `PCollection<ProducerRecord<K, V>>` as an input - so, you just need to specify a required output topic for in `ProducerRecord` for every element or use a default one.

Please, take a look on [this test](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/f16d5d51b7551c12a854833676fc5a20bf8b6702/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIOTest.java#L1391) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Some Beam sinks (like BigQueryIO) have support for "dynamic destinations" but this isn't the case for KafkaIO. You'll need to set up 3 different sinks for the different topics and you'll need to split up your messages (perhaps using a `Partition` transform) to separate collections to feed into those sinks.